# Custom Events in Admob Mediation adding unsupported Ad Networks

Tags: android, admob

I have read everything about how to implement the Custom Events in the Admob Mediation.
I have added the full packaged class name and everything is set in the Admob portal.

This is the class implementation done

```
  public class CustomEvent implements CustomEventBanner, AdListener{

private CustomEventBannerListener bannerListener;
private AdView adView;

@Override
public void requestBannerAd(final CustomEventBannerListener listener,
        final Activity activity,
        String label,
        String serverParameter,
        AdSize adSize,
        MediationAdRequest mediationAdRequest) {
    // Keep the custom event listener for use later.
    this.bannerListener = listener;

    // Determine the best ad format to use given the adSize. If the adSize
    // isn't appropriate for any format, an ad will not fill.
    AdSize bestAdSize = adSize = adSize.findBestSize(
            AdSize.BANNER,
            AdSize.IAB_BANNER,
            AdSize.IAB_LEADERBOARD,
            AdSize.IAB_MRECT,
            AdSize.IAB_WIDE_SKYSCRAPER);
    if (bestAdSize == null) {
        listener.onFailedToReceiveAd();
        return;
    }

    // Initialize an AdView with the bestAdSize and the publisher ID.
    // The publisher ID is the server parameter that you gave when creating
    // the custom event.
    this.adView = new AdView(activity, bestAdSize, serverParameter);

    // Set the listener to register for events.
    this.adView.setAdListener(this);
    // Generate an ad request using custom targeting values provided in the
    // MediationAdRequest.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest()
    .setBirthday(mediationAdRequest.getBirthday())
    .setGender(mediationAdRequest.getGender())
    .setKeywords(mediationAdRequest.getKeywords())
    .setLocation(mediationAdRequest.getLocation());
    if (mediationAdRequest.isTesting()) {
        adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
    }

    // Load the ad with the ad request.
    this.adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}

@Override
public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) {
    this.bannerListener.onReceivedAd(this.adView);
}

@Override
public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad ad, ErrorCode errorCode) {
    this.bannerListener.onFailedToReceiveAd();
}

@Override
public void onPresentScreen(Ad ad) {
    this.bannerListener.onClick();
    this.bannerListener.onPresentScreen();
}

@Override
public void onDismissScreen(Ad ad) {
    this.bannerListener.onDismissScreen();
}

@Override
public void onLeaveApplication(Ad ad) {
    this.bannerListener.onLeaveApplication();
}


}
```

The problem is that I really dont know how to add use my layout.add(adview) in the onReceivedAd(),

Any inputs would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Custom Events are a little different compared to normal AdMob implementation.  In `requestBannerAd` you create your ad network's adview, and request an ad.  Once an ad is received (in this the `onReceiveAd` callback), you invoke:

`this.bannerListener.onReceivedAd(this.adView);`

You're already doing this in your code.  When invoking this, you're telling the AdMob Mediation layer "Hey, I successfully loaded an ad, and here is my view for you to show."  The Mediation layer takes in your adview and essentially calls `layout.addView(adView)` on your behalf (it adds it as a child of the main AdView you defined in your app).

So in your case, this code should just work.

Comment: I get an illegal state exception, like `you can't add a child , as the parent already consists of a child view, call remove view on parent first.` in the requestBannerAd() method, can you provide me with a working sample , would really help

Comment: That's odd - that shouldn't happen unless you incorrectly called `adView.addView()` somewhere on your original `AdView`.  Can you confirm that this happens in `this.bannerListener.onReceivedAd(this.adView);` by putting a logging statement before and after that call and seeing if this error happens in between?